# How to fix double tap speed distance using Kivy?

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd, mobile-development

I'm trying to create a single tap and double tap inputs and what I want to happen is that when i double tap it does not get the value of the single tap.

This is what I did. I tried putting "if not touch.is_double_tap:" but it still shows the single tap value. I even tried commenting out the "with open('save_file.csv', 'a', newline='') as f: print(f"Made,{x},{y}", file=f)" below the if not touch.is_double_tap. Still getting that value.

```
 def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        d = 10

        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.canvas.add(Color(rgb=(46 / 255.0, 172 / 255.0, 88 / 255.0)))
            self.canvas.add(Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y), size=(d, d)))

            x = touch.x - self.pos[0]
            y = self.size[1] - touch.y + self.pos[1]  # modified line

            # Don't write to the file if the touch event is a double tap
            if not touch.is_double_tap:
                with open('save_file.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
                    print(f"Made,{x},{y}", file=f)
                # Increment the shots made counter
                self.shots_made += 1

            if touch.is_double_tap:
                self.canvas.add(Color(rgb=(220 / 255.0, 8 / 255.0, 8 / 255.0)))
                d = 10
                self.canvas.add(Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y), size=(d, d)))
                self.shots_missed += 1
                with open('save_file.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
                    print(f"Missed,{x},{y}", file=f)
```

What could be the possible solution for this?

Comment: look in your kivy/config.ini file for [postproc]
double_tap_time = 250
double_tap_distance = 20

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a double tap consists of **two** single taps. And during the first tap you don't know whether it will be a single or a double tap, so you can't immediately react to the first tap.

You can schedule an event (`do_your_single_tap_thing`) when you register a single tap to be executed 1 second in the future. If no second tap event registers within 1 second - this event will be executed.
If there is a second tap within one second - you delete the scheduled event and execute `do_your_double_tap_thing`

```
scheduled_event = None
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if touch.is_double_tap:
        if self.scheduled_event is not None:
            # delete the single tap event so it is never executed
            self.scheduled_event.cancel()                 
            self.scheduled_event = None
            do_your_double_tap_thing()
    else:
        double_tap_time_sec = 1 
        # alternatively, you can pull the double tap wait time 
        # from the config: Config.getint('postproc', 'double_tap_time')/1000.
        self.scheduled_event = Clock.schedule_once(do_your_single_tap_thing, double_tap_time_sec)

def do_your_single_tap_thing(self, *args):
    print("Single tap")

def do_your_double_tap_thing(self, *args):
    print("Double tap")
```

Comment: Hi, I tried including my code, the _self.canvas.add_ in the "do_your_double_tap_thing" but I'm receiving this error. _in do_your_single_tap_thing
     if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
 AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'pos'_

Comment: You need to pass your "touch" object to the function if you want to use it there. 
Alternatively, you can define the function in the `on_touch_down` function.

Comment: I tried paasing the "touch" object, but it is getting this error _do_your_single_tap_thing
     x = touch.x - self.pos[0]
 AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'x'_.. As for the alternative, it is still getting the Made value even if it was a double tap

Comment: This error means that "touch" variable's type is float. You should investigate how did it change types